# Keep purchased contents while updating

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4, in-app-purchase

i have music application for certain artist, it contains different albums where user can purchase each album alone, when certain album is purchased, its button changed from buy to play, and the songs of this album will be listed in the app, but when i did an updated version, i figured out that when the user updates his application it will reset like it was by default, play buttons will be replaced by buy buttons, and the user has to re-download the albums that he already purchased in the first version, how can i keep all the contents available in all versions,

thats how the button changes its image from "buy" to "play" in the table view3

```
 NSArray *myPathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *myPath = [myPathList objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* storagePath = [myPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"purchasedAlbums.plist"];
NSArray* valueList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:storagePath];

UIImage *change1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"playalbum-06.png"];
UIImage *change2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"playalbum-07.png"];
UIImage *change3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"playalbum-08.png"];
UIImage *change4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"playalbum-09.png"];
UIImage *change5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"playalbum-11.png"];
UIImage *change6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"playalbum-12.png"];
UIImage *change7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"playalbum-10.png"];
UIImage *change8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"playalbum-13.png"];
UIImage *change9 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipadplay-16.png"];
UIImage *change10 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipadplay-17.png"];
UIImage *change11 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipadplay-18.png"];
UIImage *change12 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipadplay-19.png"];
UIImage *change13 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipadplay-20.png"];
UIImage *change14 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipadplay-21.png"];

int i;
for (i = 0; i < [AlbumsImages count]; i++) {


if ([[valueList objectAtIndex:i+1] intValue]) {
    if (i == 0) {
        [AlbumsImages replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:change1];
    }
    if (i == 1) {
        [AlbumsImages replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:change2];
    }
    if (i == 2) {
        [AlbumsImages replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:change3];
    }
    if (i == 3) {
        [AlbumsImages replaceObjectAtIndex:3 withObject:change4];
    }
    if (i == 4) {
        [AlbumsImages replaceObjectAtIndex:4 withObject:change5];
    }
    if (i == 5) {
        [AlbumsImages replaceObjectAtIndex:5 withObject:change6];
    }
    if (i == 6) {
        [AlbumsImages replaceObjectAtIndex:6 withObject:change7];
    }
    if (i == 7) {
        [AlbumsImages replaceObjectAtIndex:7 withObject:change8];
    }
    if (i == 8) {
        [AlbumsImages replaceObjectAtIndex:8 withObject:change9];
    }
    if (i == 9) {
        [AlbumsImages replaceObjectAtIndex:9 withObject:change10];
    }
    if (i == 10) {
        [AlbumsImages replaceObjectAtIndex:10 withObject:change11];
    }
    if (i == 11) {
        [AlbumsImages replaceObjectAtIndex:11 withObject:change12];
    }
    if (i == 12) {
        [AlbumsImages replaceObjectAtIndex:12 withObject:change13];
    }
    if (i == 13) {
        [AlbumsImages replaceObjectAtIndex:13 withObject:change14];
    }
```

And thats where the albums saved when downloading

```
request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
                [request setDownloadDestinationPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Caches"] 
                                                     stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3",[self FileNameGetter:Albumid FileID:CurrentSongID ]]]];
```

And thats what happen when the application did load

```
NSArray *myPathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *myPath = [myPathList objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* storagePath = [myPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"purchasedAlbums.plist"];
NSArray* valueList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:storagePath];
if ([valueList count]==0) {
    valueList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"0" ,@"0" ,@"0" , @"0" ,@"0" ,@"0" , @"0" ,@"0" ,@"0" , @"0" ,@"0" ,@"0" , @"0" ,@"0" ,@"0" , nil];
    [valueList writeToFile:storagePath atomically:true];
} 
valueList=nil;
myPathList=nil;
myPath =nil;
storagePath =nil;
[valueList release];
[myPathList release];
[myPath release];
[storagePath release];
```

i really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want just to keep content trough your updates, save it in DocumentsDirectory instead of Caches.

And for holding the purchase progress, you can use `restoreTransactions`.

Comment: i used to save them in DocumentsDirectory before, but Apple rejected the application, so i saved them in the caches, ????

Comment: Add **dontBackUp** flag for those files, so they won't be synced with iCloud

Comment: dude can i set 'dontbackup' for the documents dir? and how can i check if the files inside documents dir is flagged with 'dontbackup'??